# Generics Collections PECS

Tags: java

I have a question about this method from `java.util.Collections`:

```
public class Collections {  
  public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {  
      for (int i=0; i<src.size();i++)   
        dest.set(i,src.get(i));   
  }   
}
```

I understand how `<? super T>` works, however,  I don't understand why the first parameter is `List<? super T>` instead of `List<T>`. I think it's useless in this situation.
Using `List<T>` should work as well, shouldn't it?
Could you give me some examples to understand it if possible, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it makes sense. For example, consider this situation:

- `T` is `InputStream`
- `dest` is a `List<Object>`
- `src` is a `List<FileInputStream>`

That works absolutely fine. Of course, you *could* make `T` either `Object` or `FileInputStream` in this situation - but imagine you were calling this *from* a method with a signature of:

```
public void doSomething(List<? super InputStream> streams) {
    // I want to use copy in here for some reason
}
```

You don't know it's a `List<InputStream>` - only that it's a `List<? super InputStream>`. If the `dest` parameter in `copy` were *just* `List<T>`, we'd be stuck... but with the way it *is* written, we're fine.

It also makes sense in terms of what we require from the destination list - we *just* need to be able to set values of `T` within it. Likewise all we require of the source list is that we can get values of `T` from it. `<? super T>` and `<? extends T>` express those requirements well.

Answer (score 0):

If you break it down in why the List is being used it will be a bit more clear.

When a method intends to populate a list, you could restrict it to use a specific type T, however often you might want to be less restrictive.

For example, lets say you have a method `populateWithStudents(List<Student> list)`
And you have `Student extend Person`

This means that you can't use that method with a `List<Person>` to fill it with Student objects, even though Student extends Person.

So if on the other hand we would like to allow that we change it to `populateWithStudents(List<? super Student> list)`. This way we're saying that as long as we can fit a Student in the list, no matter if it is a list of Student objects, or a list of any of its superclasses, it is allowed.

This is not just when populating obviously, but this example helps understand the concept.