# Java, generics and PECS: still having trouble understanding the C part; concrete example?

Tags: java, generics, pecs

I'll post a single link here: [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29). There have been many posts on SO with regards to the PECS paradigm, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856109/generics-collections-pecs). In my own personal code, I use generics quite a lot, but have only ever had the use of the P part (that is, `<X extends SomethingElse>`).

`Collections.sort` expects as its generics argument a `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`. I fail to see where the `super` kicks in in there. Do you have a concrete example of why this is necessary?

While I am at it, I am deeply afraid that I don't understand the full implications of P either... I have read many, many links, without having had a clear, obvious proof that P is P and C is C...

**EDIT** As to the may already have an answer here": no, sorry. I have read this link, and many others on SO. This still does not tell me the core mechanism behind it all. The two answers given to me so far give me hints, in fact more so than all the links I could find so far.

Comment: May be take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1679863

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/1679863) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1368166/1679863)

Comment: I _know_ all of these. I am no the wiser. I have read all these links before, without being able to grasp the _real need_.

Comment: Go through [this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) site. This is AFAIK, the best resource on Java Generics.

Comment: @RohitJain I also know this site, and I have read the FAQ a number of times. Mrs Langer is a name I know.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
List<Interger> myIntegers = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 3);

List<Long> myLongs = Arrays.asList(5L, 2L, 3L);

MyNumberComparator myNumberComparator = new Comparator<Number>(){...}

Collections.sort(myIntegers, myNumberComparator ); // Number is "super" class of Integer
Collections.sort(myLongs , myNumberComparator ); // Number is "super" class of Long
```

So "super" here allows to reuse MyNumberComparator for both sorting Integers and sorting Longs.

Comment: Now we're talking/starting to talk! This is a good example indeed! I'll read that again, find more uses of it, but your example at least expresses _one need_ for `super` clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I fail to see where the super kicks in in there. Do you have a
>   concrete example of why this is necessary?

Say you have a class `Animal`, which is comparable to all `Animal`s:

```
public class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>
```

Now let's say you have a class `Dog`, which extends `Animal`:

```
public class Dog extends Animal
```

Now the question is, can `Dog` compare to another `Dog`? (i.e. can you do `myDog.compareTo(yourDog)`) The answer is of course. A `Dog`, as an `Animal`, is comparable to all `Animal`s, including `Dog`s (as well as `Cat`s).

However, `Dog` does not implement `Comparable<Dog>`, so a bound `T extends Comparable<T>` would not work for `T = Dog`.

But for sorting all we care is that the type can compare to itself (which `Dog` can do). So the suitable least restrictive bound is `T extends Comparable<? super T>`, which does work for `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a List of Number :

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>(Arrays.asList(2, 3.14, 5, 0, 42, 2.5));
```

Now try to sort it :

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Looking at the generic argument `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, it equivalent in this case to `<Number extends Comparable<? super Number>>`. However the Number class doesn't implement such a comparator. Hence the code does'nt compile and it forces you to create your own one.

Comment: You're French, aren't you? ;) So am I. Your 'Or' should be 'However' ;)