# "Type mismatch" for function returning itself recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a function that returns a type of generic class `K` which extends the `Comparable` interface. This function calls itself recursively. Interestingly, when it gets called I receive the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparable to K.`

```
public class NonEmptyTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Tree<K, V> {
    Tree right;
    K key;
    ...
    public K max() throws EmptyTreeException {
        try {
            return right.max(); // "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparable to K"
        } catch (EmptyTreeException e) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Changing the return statement to `return (K) right.max();` removes the error and produces the expected behavior.

Why is the cast necessary and how can I produce the code such that does not require casting?

Comment: Is `key` of type `K`?

Comment: a) [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17192772/995891): `<K extends Comparable<? super K>>` b) where / how is `right` defined?

Comment: @Tom Yes, `key` is of type `K`.
@zapl `right` is of type `Tree`, which the class extends.

Comment: @ahe Just `Tree` or `Tree<K, V>`? Ah I see your edit now. The problem is, that you use the raw type of `Tree`. Change it to match the generic type.

Comment: @Tom Solved it, thank you!

Comment: @ahe Your class implements `Tree<K, V>`, but `right` only has `Tree` without a specific generic type. That means `right.max()` could return anything and not necessarily the same type as defined for `K`. (Edit: glad it helped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the declaration of `right`.

Rather than

```
Tree right;
```

It should be:

```
Tree<K, V> right;
```